# How to sequently show words in label or other display widget in gtk2hs?

Tags: windows, haskell, windows-7, gtk2hs

I need to represent words in label (or other display type widget) sequentially

, using **gtk2hs**.

I tried this:

```
import Graphics.UI.Gtk
import Control.Concurrent

main = do 
    initGUI
    window <- windowNew
    window `onDestroy` mainQuit

    lay <- vBoxNew False 0

    but <-buttonNewWithLabel "Sequently show one, two and three"

    lab <- labelNew Nothing

    onPressed but $ do
        labelSetText lab "one"
        threadDelay 1000000
        labelSetText lab "two"
        threadDelay 1000000
        labelSetText lab "three"

    containerAdd window lay
    containerAdd lay but
    containerAdd lay lab

    widgetShowAll window
    onDestroy window mainQuit
    mainGUI
```

I think, that it should show "one" in `label`, wait 1 second, show "two", wait one second, and then show "three", when I press the button.
**But** this only shows "three" in `label` after 2 seconds after I pressed the button.

I also tried `Statusbar`, which gives same result.

P. S.: Maybe it's windows-specific?

P. P. S.: gtk2hs is 0.12.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to run new thread!

We need to put `forkIO` in the body of `onPressed`:

```
onPressed but $ do
    forkIO $ do
        set lab [labelText:="one"]
        threadDelay 1000000
        set lab [labelText:="two"]
        threadDelay 1000000
        set lab [labelText:="three"]
    return()
```

It works fine now!

Comment: Gtk doesn't play nice with other threads. Particularly, Gtk calls from outside the main Gtk thread (as is your case) can be nasty. You should read http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Gtk2Hs/Tutorials/ThreadedGUIs.

Comment: Yeah, @AlfonsoVillén, I know, that I need HAX. =)
I've read this. http://projects.haskell.org/gtk2hs/archives/2005/07/24/writing-multi-threaded-guis/

Comment: That article doesn't say anything about `postAsyncGUI`, which the other articles mentions. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, @AlfonsoVillén. It working successfully. With compilation.